# Android studio 3.0 missing drawable folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I'm new to Android development, and I'm trying to follow tutorials on the web. One thing that I've noticed is that the drawable folder is missing from 3.0, and behaving differently form older versions of AS if created manually.

**Default View:**
[image]

---

After adding the directories manually I still can't reference my image.

[image]

---

What am I missing?

Comment: create yourself that's set

Comment: use mipmap folder as drawable or rename it with drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new folder:

Right click 'res' folder -> New -> Android Resource Directory.

or set alternative resource. such as

```
   android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: please try it. it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new folder:

Right click 'res' folder -> New -> Android Resource Directory.

In the wizard, select drawable as 'Resource Type'. And then 'Density' from the resource qualifiers.

With regard to the 'mipmaps' folders, Android now [prefers](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) app icons in these folders because it can use an icon in a different density to the screen density.

or

You can put your `logo.png` inside mipmap folder, that you've and use.

```
android:background="@mipmap/logo"
```

Comment: There is no "drawable" resource type in android studio 3.0

Comment: You're right. I checked, now in 3.0 you've to select `mipmap` Resource type then `Density` in qualifiers.

Comment: But using the mipmap folder is reserved for launcher icons and not general images, according to google's guidelines

Comment: You can create directory inside `res` folder with `drawable` name then put your resource like `logo.png` in that folder. You can access that resource by `R.drawable.logo` but obviously `mipmap` is preferable.

Comment: Why do you say mipmap is preferable when google explicitly says you should not use it like this?

Comment: You should keep your images in mipmap that are often scaled up (or extremely scaled down) and whose quality is critical for the app and rest of the images go for drawables.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create drawable folder if you want ... and drawable folder not necessary for anything you can create new folder with any name to contain same files

Answer (score 0):

Add new folder and named it as drawable. Put your logo there or you can use mipmap folders for logo.

Right click on res > new > directory > name it drawable.